# Using Averageif for 2 criteria in an Array in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel

I'm trying to use the `Averageif(s)` formula for an array with two criteria for data that is in columnar form, with skill (i.e, SAP, column C), company (i.e, Facebook, column D), and rate (i.e, $25, column E).

I'd like the find the average rate for each skill with the following criteria:

1. the averageif formula will ignore 0s so as to not skew the average
2. the averageif formula will take the average of each skill.

So far I've tried `=AVERAGEIF($C$7:$C$138,C7=$C$7:$C$138,$E$7:$E$138)` but it is showing a `#DIV/0` error.

How do I incorporate criteria #1 into the formula?
Thank you!

Comment: It would be easier if you provided some example of your input data and expected output, so we don't have to reproduce your whole table from 0. Ps.: have you tried using a pivot table?

Comment: Sure example data:  SAP, FB, $25 (row 1), SAP, Google, $23 (row 2), SAP, Oracle, $0 or blank (row 3).  Expected result (average of FB and Google rates, ignoring the 0): $24 for the SAP skillset among a group of companies.

Comment: To incorporate if it's not 0, it'd be for example `=AverageIf($E$7:$E$138,"<>0")`.  Also could you kindly post some sample data in to your original post? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try `AVERAGEIFS` like this

`=AVERAGEIFS($E$7:$E$138,$E$7:$E$138,"<>0",$C$7:$C$138,C7)`